# Stacked bar graph with variable width elements?

Tags: python, r, graph, ggplot2, data-visualization

In Tableau I'm used to making graphs like the one below. It has for each day (or some other discrete variable), a stacked bar of categories of different colours, heights and widths.

You can imagine the categories to be different advertisements that I show to people. The heights correspond to the percentage of people I've shown the advertisement to, and the widths correspond to the rate of acceptance.

It allows me to see very easily which advertisements I should probably show more often (short, but wide bars, like the 'C' category on September 13th and 14th) and which I should show less often (tall, narrow bars, like the 'H' category on September 16th).

Any ideas on how I could create a graph like this in R or Python?

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could provide some sample data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not so trivial to achieve with `ggplot2` (I think), because `geom_bar` does not really support changing widths for the same x position. But with a bit of effort, we can achieve the same result:

#### Create some fake data

```
set.seed(1234)
d <- as.data.frame(expand.grid(adv = LETTERS[1:7], day = 1:5))
d$height <- runif(7*5, 1, 3)
d$width <- runif(7*5, 0.1, 0.3)
```

My data doesn't add up to 100%, cause I'm lazy.

```
head(d, 10)

#    adv day   height     width
# 1    A   1 1.227407 0.2519341
# 2    B   1 2.244599 0.1402496
# 3    C   1 2.218549 0.1517620
# 4    D   1 2.246759 0.2984301
# 5    E   1 2.721831 0.2614705
# 6    F   1 2.280621 0.2106667
# 7    G   1 1.018992 0.2292812
# 8    A   2 1.465101 0.1623649
# 9    B   2 2.332168 0.2243638
# 10   C   2 2.028502 0.1659540
```

#### Make a new variable for stacking

We can't easily use `position_stack` I think, so we'll just do that part ourselves. Basically, we need to calculate the cumulative height for every bar, grouped by day. Using `dplyr` we can do that very easily.

```
library(dplyr)
d2 <- d %>% group_by(day) %>% mutate(cum_height = cumsum(height))
```

#### Make the plot

Finally, we create the plot. Note that the `x` and `y` refer to the *middle* of the tiles.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d2, aes(x = day, y = cum_height - 0.5 * height, fill = adv)) +
  geom_tile(aes(width = width, height = height), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = adv)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual', palette = 2) +
  labs(title = "Views and other stuff", y = "% of views")
```

If you don't want to play around with correctly scaling the widths (to something < 1), you can use facets instead:

```
ggplot(d2, aes(x = 1, y = cum_height - 0.5 * height, fill = adv)) +
  geom_tile(aes(width = width, height = height), show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = adv)) +
  facet_grid(~day) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual', palette = 2) +
  labs(title = "Views and other stuff", y = "% of views", x = "")
```

#### Result

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

```
set.seed(1)
days <- 5
cats <- 8
dat <- prop.table(matrix(rpois(days * cats, days), cats), 2)

bp1 <- barplot(dat, col = seq(cats))
```

[image]

```
## some width for rect
rate <- matrix(runif(days * cats, .1, .5), cats)

## calculate xbottom, xtop, ybottom, ytop
bp   <- rep(bp1, each = cats)
ybot <- apply(rbind(0, dat), 2, cumsum)[-(cats + 1), ]
ytop <- apply(dat, 2, cumsum)

plot(extendrange(bp1), c(0,1), type = 'n', axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE)
rect(bp - rate, ybot, bp + rate, ytop, col = seq(cats))

text(bp, (ytop + ybot) / 2, LETTERS[seq(cats)])
axis(1, bp1, labels = format(Sys.Date() + seq(days), '%d %b %Y'), lwd = 0)
axis(2)
```

[image]

Probably not very useful, but you can invert the color you are plotting so that you can actually see the labels:

```
inv_col <- function(color) {
  paste0('#', apply(apply(rbind(abs(255 - col2rgb(color))), 2, function(x)
    format(as.hexmode(x), 2)), 2, paste, collapse = ''))
}

inv_col(palette())
# [1] "#ffffff" "#00ffff" "#ff32ff" "#ffff00" "#ff0000" "#00ff00" "#0000ff" "#414141"


plot(extendrange(bp1), c(0,1), type = 'n', axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE)
rect(bp - rate, ybot, bp + rate, ytop, col = seq(cats), xpd = NA, border = NA)

text(bp, (ytop + ybot) / 2, LETTERS[seq(cats)], col = inv_col(seq(cats)))
axis(1, bp1, labels = format(Sys.Date() + seq(days), '%d %B\n%Y'), lwd = 0)
axis(2)
```

[image]